# How do I get the current viewmodel from androidx navcontroller backstack entry?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, dagger-hilt

When a event happens, I want to relay the information to the current viewmodel if it implements a specific interface, if the current viewmodel doesn't implement this interface I want to handle this event in a default way.

I tried getting the currentViewModel from the current backstack entry but there is no way to get the viewmodel without knowing what class it is.

How do I solve this? or is there a better pattern for this?

Comment: You need access to `ViewModelStore` that holds references to the viewmodels, that's impossible to obtain from backstack entry.

Comment: currentBackStackEntry have access to the viewModelStore but it only contains a clear() function. Any idea how to solve it in a other way?

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavBackStackEntry

Comment: But you are unable to access map in the `ViewModelStore`